# How to request a refund from Condor Airlines without calling them?

Tags: refunds, condor

A friend of mine had a ticket with Condor airlines from Seattle to Prague, scheduled to depart on March 16th via Frankfurt. The Frankfurt-Prague flight (LH1400) was cancelled, so my friend would like to receive a refund on the return part of their flight.

However Condor's phone agents are impossible to reach right now. Is it possible to somehow ask for a refund via email? Their website doesn't seem to offer such an option.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the contact form mentioned in the website.

https://www.condor.com/us/help-contact/faq.jsp

You can also try to reach them using social media. I was able to reach a different airline through social media when calls was not going through.