# Flight Cancelled due to Covid

Tags: air-travel, cancellations, refunds, tap-portugal

Our family's flight to Portugal from Canada scheduled in May 2020 was cancelled by the TAP Portgual airline due to Covid. Since we are unlikely to be able to travel there within a couple of years we have been trying to obtain a refund from the airline without luck. Have tried calling, filing a complaint on their website, and attempted refund through my credit card insurance without any luck. As far as I can see on their website they only give the option for a voucher which would be useless for us. The amount was over $2000 Canadian.

As far as I understand they are obligated to provide a refund since the flight was cancelled.

Any advice?

Thank you

Comment: Did you ask for  a chargeback on your credit card (see this related questions to the right.) https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/155155/can-i-simply-apply-for-a-chargeback-on-my-credit-card-if-my-flight-was-cancelled?rq=1

Comment: @Willeke: probably too late for a chargeback: https://www.chargebackgurus.com/blog/dont-run-out-the-clock-understanding-chargeback-time-limits#:~:text=Cardholders%20have%20a%2075%2D120,counterfeit%20or%20non%2Dcounterfeit%20fraud